# Jquery Full Calendar- Month name to be passed as a parameter to database when prev and next is clicked

Tags: c#, jquery, fullcalendar

Team,

I am new to jquery and C#. I am trying to integrate jquery Full calendar plugin with the code in C# to show leaves taken up by company resources.There are more than 10,000 records in the database which i would like to filter by fiscal year and fiscal month.So I would like to pass in the two parameters to the C# db code (year and month) when i click on prev and next buttons.

I am able to display the first 500 rows from the db on the calendar( I guess i cannot display more than that--Seems a limitation)

Below is the code

js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: "{}",
            url: "CalendarPage.aspx/GetEvents",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('div[id*=fullcal]').fullCalendar({


                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    events: $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                        //var eventsUrl = '/events/' + end.year() + '/' + parseInt(end.month());
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.id = item.EventID;
                        event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
                        event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
                        event.title = item.EventName;
                        event.url = item.Url;
                        event.ImageType = item.ImageType;

                        return event;
                    }), eventRender: function (event, eventElement) {
                        if (event.ImageType) {
                            if (eventElement.find('span.fc-event-time').length) {
                                eventElement.find('span.fc-event-time').before($(GetImage(event.ImageType)));
                            } else {
                                eventElement.find('span.fc-event-title').before($(GetImage(event.ImageType)));
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    loading: function (bool) {
                        if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                        else $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('div[id*=fullcal]').show();
    });
    function GetImage(type) {
        if (type == 0) {
            return "<br/><img src = 'Styles/Images/attendance.png' style='width:24px;height:24px'/><br/>"
        }
        else if (type == 1) {
            return "<br/><img src = 'Styles/Images/not_available.png' style='width:24px;height:24px'/><br/>"
        }
        else
            return "<br/><img src = 'Styles/Images/not_available.png' style='width:24px;height:24px'/><br/>"
    }

</script>
```

C# code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static IList GetEvents()
    {


        Leave_Management_Leave_TakenTableAdapter LTTA = new Leave_Management_Leave_TakenTableAdapter();

        DB.Leave_Management_Leave_TakenDataTable LTTbl = null;

        **LTTbl = LTTA.GetForCalendar("I wish to put the parameters here");**
        IList events = new List<Event>();



            foreach( DataRow dr in LTTbl.Rows)
            {
                events.Add(new Event
                {


                    EventName = dr["Fullname"] + " Leave",

                 //   DateTime dt = , 

                   StartDate = DateTime.Parse(dr["leave_days"].ToString()).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")




                });


            }

        return events;
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest any changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fullcalendar passes 2 GET parameters anytime it makes a request for data, if you add (DateTime start, DateTime end) to your GetEvents method you can filter your data for the given range.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: thanks for your update. I had tried that..however I  would require after I click on prev/next button at the top left. The GetEvents webservice method does not get a call when I click on the prev next button. Is there a way to do it please?

Comment: Instead of making an ajax call to then initialise the calendar allow the calendar to do it itself. If you set the events option of the calendar to your url and return json from your web method it will still populate the calendar as you expect, however when you click previous or next it will call the same url passing the 2 GET parameters. If you have a look a the link in the answer I provided it explains this further.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I implemented yours and got through it. However I have found one more way . It works and is a simple solution to bring in max number of events on the calendar. Please note that only max of 500 events were populated and I felt that was a limitation of the control. The solution is as mentioned below.

Comment: When you say you can bring back the max number of events you may want to be careful with this, you could end up with a lot of data and it could affect performance. Using the start and end dates that are passed to the web method allows you to query the database for the dates actually in range saving you from pulling unnecessary data into memory. Thanks for accepting the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I thought earlier that the control faced a limitation of populating around 700-800 event records on the calendar. On further investigating, I stumbled on a piece of code to be placed in the web.config. This basically maximizes the lenght of jsonserialization string.

```
<system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
```